# Customized date format in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to format my date like this "2016-04-19T03:35:17.02". How can i format date format like using javascript or jQuery.

Please help me any one this.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? This isn't a code writing service and as it stands your question shows no research effort at all

Comment: Check out this documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Really you must do some research and then call up for help..

Answer (score -1):

In javascript you have a Date object. First you must create the object:

```
var d = new Date();
```

Then you can make a variable for each of the pieces you want:

```
// Get the year
var year = d.getFullYear();

// Get the month +1 because normally returns 0-11
var month = d.getMonth()+1;

// Format month to add a 0 if 1-9
var fMonth = month < 9 ? '0' + month : month;

// Get day and format it to add a 0 if 1-9
var fDay =  d.getDate() < 9 ? '0' + d.getDate() : d.getDate();

// Combine it into a single string
var dateStr = year +'-'+ fMonth +'-'+ fDay +'T';
```

That should get you "2016-05-22T".  The rest you can complete on your own.  You can use w3schools list of available Date methods: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: There's a single method that'd do this for the asker, but evidently they did not research their issue before coming here for help. Assisting them anyway just proves them that their question was welcome while in fact it was not.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine though, I had the time and wanted to take the opportunity to share with him some Javascript knowledge

Answer (score -2):

You can use these methods `getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate(), getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(), getMilliseconds()` or just some library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), where you can just use method `.format()` and it's parameters.